# Сделать чтобы содержимое textView в item в recyclerView отображалось только после клика на itemView - как?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

recyclerView заполняется объектами,объект имеет 2 стринга: name and status. Соответственно для
отображения есть два textView: mName и mStatus (см. onBindViewHolder внизу). Мне нужно, чтобы
изначально было прописано только mName, а только после клика на itemView появлялся текст mStatus.
Я запустил onClickListener из адаптера в Activity, но не понимаю как это там прописать (см. Activity).

In Activity:

```
//variables and methods etc..
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(new MyAdapter.MyDiff()); 
myCardStackLayoutManager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, this);
myCardStackView.setLayoutManager(myCardStackLayoutManager);
myCardStackView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.setOnCardListener(new MyAdapter.OnCardListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCardClick(int position) {
        // WHAT TO TYPE HERE?
    }
});
```

In Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ListAdapter<Person, MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private OnCardListener mOnCardListener; 
    public interface OnCardListener {
        void onCardClick(int position);
    } 
    public void setOnCardListener(OnCardListener onCardListener) {
        mOnCardListener = onCardListener;
    }
// variables and methods...
public static class MyViewHolder extends CardStackView.ViewHolder /*implements View.OnClickListener*/ { //NEWWW
        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mStatus;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnCardListener onCardListener) {   //NEWWW
            super(itemView);
            mName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            mStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (onCardListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != CardStackView.NO_POSITION) {
                            onCardListener.onCardClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
// other methods
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Person currentPerson = getItem(position);
        holder.mName.setText(currentPerson.getName());
        holder.mStatus.setText(currentPerson.getStatus()); //это изначально не должно отображаться, а только после клика.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте в Person переменную, хранящую состояние видимости статуса.
2. По клику на ячейку списка - меняйте состояние на противоположное. И уведомлейте адаптер об изменениях.
3. В onBindViewHolder в зависимости от значения переменной из п.1 меняйте видимость нужного текстового поля.